# Divide RGB values in text file

Tags: bash

I have a text file that has RGB values. I need each value to be divided by `255` then save it to a new text file, or print to console.

The text file with RGB values (two spaces before each number):

```
42  107   40  #

50  114   41  #
```

needs to be changed to something like (only need one space between numbers):

```
0.164706 0.419608 0.156862

0.196078 0.447059 0.160784
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` can do this efficiently

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i/255; print $0}' inputfile
```

OR

a shorter version

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i/255}1' inputfile
```

will provide the output as

```
0.164706 0.419608 0.156863
0.196078 0.447059 0.160784
```

What it does?

`NF` number of fields or columns in the line. by default seperated by spaces.

`for (i=1;i<=NF;i+) $i=$i/255` `$i` selects the ith column divides it by 255

`print $0` will print the entire record.

Comment: make it simple `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i/255;}1' file`

Comment: That works great for the first column, however I need all three columns.

Comment: @AvinashRaj much shorter. Thank you :)